# unable to enable sierra modem due to policykit

Tags: modem, policykit, modem-manager

I have a machine running ubuntu 16.04 and mmcli 1.6.4 with a Sierra MC7710 modem installed. It's currently showing

```
mmcli -m 0 -w
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: Initial state, 'disabled'
```

when i try and enable it

```
mmcli -m 0 -e
```

I get the following error

```
error: couldn't enable the modem: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Failed: PolicyKit authorization failed: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files''
```

Comment: What kind of system is this (server, desktop, VPS?). Is the `policykit-1` package installed?

Comment: Yes it was installed but after uninstalling/re-installing it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalled policykit and re-installed with

```
sudo apt-get install policykit-1
```

and the command then worked.